# How to sort datagridview with datetime as string

Tags: sql, vb.net, sorting, datagridview

How would I create a datagridview with the following columns:

- [Part Serial Number]
- [Part Number]
- [Date Time]
- [Description]
- [Side]
- [Event Outcome]
- [Event Outcome Info]

I've attempted to create a dgv like this but my problem lies with the sorting.  All of the fields come in as strings and I cannot get the [Date Time] to sort at all. Is it possible to have a dgv with a column that could contain either a datetime data type or a string value?

---

More info on my scenario:
I have a form w/ a listbox that is manually filled by the end user.  This listbox contains serial numbers which may/may not exist in our SQL db.  The 1st function I call is to check if the s/n exists and return true or false depending on its existence. If it exists then I store it in an string array; if not it's stored in a List(Of String). After they're stored, I use them to return tsql code (SQLstrIn & SQLstrNotIn). This small bit of code does this very well:

```
Dim IsIn As String = ""
        Dim IsNotIn As New List(Of String)


        For Each line As String In SNList.Items
            If SQLData.CheckIfInDb("'" & line & "'") = True Then
                IsIn += "'" & line & "',"
            Else : IsNotIn.Add("('" & line & "')")
            End If
        Next

        If IsIn.Count > 0 Then
            IsIn = "(" & IsIn.Remove(IsIn.Length - 1) & ")"
            SQLstrIn = SQLData.SQLtoReturn(IsIn)
        Else : SQLstrIn = ""
        End If

        If IsNotIn.Count > 0 Then
            SQLstrNotIn = SQLData.SQLtoReturn(IsNotIn)
        Else : SQLstrNotIn = ""
        End If
```

If a s/n exists then I use this function to generate the tsql code:

```
 Public Shared Function SQLtoReturn(ByVal InStr As String) As String
    Dim SQLstr As New StringBuilder

    SQLstr.Append("SELECT DISTINCT")
    SQLstr.Append("     RTRIM(LTrim(ce.PartSerialNumber)) [Part Serial Number], ")
    SQLstr.Append("     RTRIM(LTrim(p.PartNumber)) [Part Number], ")
    SQLstr.Append("     CONVERT(varchar(10), DateTime, 101) + STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(26), DateTime, 109), 15), 7, 7, ' ') [Date Time], ")
    'SQLstr.Append("     ce.DateTime [Date Time], ")
    SQLstr.Append("     RTRIM(LTrim(cp.Description)) [Description], ")
    SQLstr.Append("     RTRIM(LTrim(cp.Side)) [Side], ")
    SQLstr.Append("     RTRIM(LTrim(ce.EventOutcome)) [Event Outcome], ")
    SQLstr.Append("     RTRIM(LTrim(ce.EventOutcomeInfo)) [Event Outcome Info] ")
    SQLstr.Append("FROM ")
    SQLstr.Append("     CollectionEvents AS ce INNER JOIN ")
    SQLstr.Append("       CollectionPoints AS cp ON ce.CollectionPointId = cp.CollectionPointId INNER JOIN ")
    SQLstr.Append("       Products AS p ON cp.ProductIdValue = p.ProductId ")
    SQLstr.Append("WHERE ")
    SQLstr.Append("     (ce.PartSerialNumber IN " & InStr & ") ")

    Return SQLstr.ToString

End Function
```

If a s/n doesn't exist then I use this function:

```
Public Shared Function SQLtoReturn(ByVal NotInStr As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim SQLstr As New StringBuilder
    Dim rtrnString As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To NotInStr.Count - 1
        SQLstr.Append("SELECT ")
        SQLstr.Append(NotInStr.Item(i).ToString & " [Part Serial Number], ")    '1  
        SQLstr.Append("'No Data Found' [Part Number], ")                        '2
        SQLstr.Append("'No Data Found' [Date Time], ")                          '3
        SQLstr.Append("'No Data Found' Description, ")                          '4
        SQLstr.Append("'No Data Found' Side, ")                                 '5
        SQLstr.Append("'No Data Found' [Event Outcome], ")                      '6
        SQLstr.Append("'No Data Found' [Event Outcome Info] ")                  '7
        If (i < NotInStr.Count - 1) Then SQLstr.Append("UNION")
        SQLstr.Append(vbCrLf)
        rtrnString += SQLstr.ToString
    Next

    Return SQLstr.ToString

End Function
```

If both functions return tsql data then they are UNIONed together; if one doesn't return tsql code then it isn't included.  This piece of code is essentially the last step:

```
If SQLstrIn.Length > 0 And SQLstrNotIn.Length > 0 Then
            SQLstr = SQLstrIn & vbNewLine & "UNION" & vbNewLine & SQLstrNotIn
        ElseIf SQLstrIn.Length > 0 And SQLstrNotIn.Length = 0 Then
            SQLstr = SQLstrIn
        ElseIf SQLstrIn.Length = 0 And SQLstrNotIn.Length > 0 Then
            SQLstr = SQLstrNotIn
        End If

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Part Serial Number", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Part Number", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("DateTime", GetType(Object))
        dt.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Side", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Event Outcome", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Event Outcome Info", GetType(String))

        Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.FISSQLConnectionString)
        objConn.Open()
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = objConn.CreateCommand
        objCommand.CommandText = SQLstr
        Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader
        If objReader.HasRows Then
            While objReader.Read
                With objReader
                    dt.Rows.Add(.GetString(0), .GetString(1), .GetValue(2), .GetString(3), .GetString(4), .GetString(5), .GetString(6))
                End With
            End While
        End If

        Dim dataview As DataView = dt.DefaultView
        dataview.Sort = "DateTime ASC"
        dgvSNEvents.DataSource = dataview.ToTable
```

I used a GetType(Object) for the DateTime field in hopes of it storing a date/time value or a string value.  Ultimately, I am still unable to sort by the s/n then the date.  Still learning the best approaches so if anyone has better ways, I'd love to see them.

---

The datetime column is still a bit off.

[image]

Comment: Can you format the date (string) so it is sortable? Would that help. IE: `format([Your Date],"s")` BTW, the "s" format is a sortable [date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362btx8f.aspx)

Comment: @Steve I tried the format on the date field currently being stored as a string but only get an "s" as my output.  Here's what I tried: Format(.GetString(2),"s").  I tried it outside of the While loop as Format(Now(),"s") and it worked, but haven't a clue why it failed otherwise.

Comment: It fails because `.GetString(2)` is not a date. The "s" type only works if the value is a date type. This should work you if you dont have nulls 'Format(.GetDate(2),"s")'

Comment: @Steve you beat me to it...i just found that out.  Do you know if the "T" can be hidden or if there is another format that is sortable and has the date & time?  I looked at the "U" but doesn't look like it can be sorted.

Comment: Something like this: `Format(.GetDate(2),"s").replace(" T "," ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of the `DataGridView` is that the columns can be sorted (i.e., by clicking on the header); in any case, you can force this behaviour by affecting the `SortMode` property. Regarding dates, you can add `Date type` columns to the given `DataSource`. Sample code for `DataGridView1`:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

dt.Columns.Add("col", GetType(Date))

dt.Rows.Add(New Date(2000, 2, 1, 10, 10, 0))
dt.Rows.Add(New Date(2002, 5, 10, 10, 10, 0))
dt.Rows.Add(New Date(1995, 5, 10, 10, 11, 10))

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic 'Just to make sure
```

Rows in `DataGridView1` will be sorted by clicking on the header of the first column. If you want to get all the records sorted from the start, you can sort the `DataSource` (`dt`); sample code:

```
Dim dataView As DataView = dt.DefaultView
dataView.Sort = "col asc"

DataGridView1.DataSource = dataView.ToTable() 'DGV sorted ascendently
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but my datetime values are coming as strings, will the .add("col", GetType(Date)) convert them?  I'll also run into a problem when no records are found for a [Part Serial Number].  When that happens a 'Data Not Found' message needs to be placed in the datetime column (actually it will be going into all the columns in the row).

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 You asked generically (without providing any code) and I have given a generic answer. If source data are date/time as strings and you want to convert them into date/time types you would have to rely on the corresponding means to carry out this action. The whole point of my answer is telling you that the standard DGV behaviour should account for what you want (dates to be sorted) OK; in any case you can always affect the datasource (which can have date-type columns). If you want more specific answers (within the original scope of the question), you would have to post some code.

Comment: I'm amending my post with some code and a bit more background.

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 your code looks surprisingly similar to what I proposed. You are doing everything OK except the part where you are adding the date/time column, you should set a date/time type (take a look at what I did) to allow a proper ordering. Logically, then you have to perform a conversion to date when writing to the DataTable.  It might even "sortable" in string format (but you are using Object, which most likely is not allowing any sorting).

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 PD: I understand that you have problems when the DGV is populated, but that the sorting occurs when the user clicks on the header; if this is not the case, you would have to set the SortMode for the given column as suggested.

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 "GetType(Object) for the DateTime field in hopes of it storing a date/time value or a string value. " -> this is not how it works. Dates cannot be implicitely assumed from object; if you take an object-type containing a valid date and cast/convert it into a date type it would work; but no automatic assumption. Actually, string tend to work better on this front (perhaps the sorting is performed with strings). Safest thing: convert explicitely to dates as suggested.

Comment: I tried your example in a test solution and works great, thanks for the help.  I did change the GetType(Date) to GetType(Object) so I can account for string values that aren't datetimes.  Would this be the best way to handle both?

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 yes (or string can deal with it too). I misunderstood your statement and thought that you expected the object to be automatically understood by the sorting method as date. If it is just a temporary storage, which you will check to generate the corresponding Date type (via Date.ParseExact, for example) or a warning message when the date is not present; it would be fine.

Comment: I added my final output table to my original post but it's still not sorting correctly.  I did change the data type for the datetime field from Object to String but it didn't affect the outcome.

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 as said, the for sure working option is converting to date. String is an easiest approach and can deliver an acceptable performance in most of the cases because alphabetical ordering accounts well for date ordering (although not always). Also you have records which, I understand that should have a special (not based on dates) ordering. All this cannot be accounted (properly) in one go; what I will do:

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 in the While objReader.Read inspect the date column and see if it includes a valid date or not; store the records in two different tables (e.g., dt1 and dt2) on account of this fact: in one table all the records with wrong date and in the other one the records with date; in this second one the given column will be of date type (and the records will be automatically converted to Date while being stored). Sort this second table on account of dates; join both tables and set this as the source -> the higher control you want on something, the less simple :)

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 I guess that all this is more than enough as an answer for your original problem. Your specific conditions require a bit of work (to deliver a good enough result), but I understand that you are question has been answered: you can sort the datasource by setting the corresponding column to date type (and, logically) by removing all the non-date records; if your requirements are a bit more complicated, you might intend to rely on string or perform a custom implementation to adapt the input conditions to what the DataSource/DGV expects.

Comment: I will give that a go as it seems like the only viable option.

Comment: I ended up using the two tables method, joining them, then sorting.  All looks/works well.

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 Thanks for letting me know. This sounded as the most adequate solution for your requirements.